# why my code echo with Resource id #6 instead of lecturer or student in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT position FROM user WHERE id ='$id' AND password = ' $password'");
echo ($sql1);
```

this is my code which i want to search the position in the database and  echo it out.

Comment: Please RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: You have a space in the password enclosed in quotes. Remove it and you will be happy.

Comment: @WeSee **NO**, will still be getting a resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of mysql_query is a handle which allows to retrieve the values of the query, for example with the functions mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_object. You have to feed the query handle to those functions, like in

```
$q = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
$position = $q['position'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove space b/w ' & $ on msql query.

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT position FROM user WHERE id ='$id' AND password = '$password'",$con);
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   foreach ($row as $value)
{
print_r ($value);
}
```

Comment: still same, it can't work

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns a `resource` or `false` on failure. This answer doesn't address OP's problem and doesn't tell anything

Comment: so what do i needed to change ?

Comment: And also this note is correct, you need to remove the space from password comparison

Comment: it's not prob with query maybe any other issues submit your whole code

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
echo $row['table_value'];
}
```

use this code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because mysql_query returns a resource on success. To get the data using the resource that you got, you can run something like the following.

```
if($sql1){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
 echo $row['position'];
}
}
```